# Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1: SASL Authentication is not supported in version 1 of the protocol

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc

Getting following exception while connecting to Cassandra Cluster withAuthentication:

Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1: SASL Authentication is not supported in version 1 of the protocol
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.waitForSaslCompletion(Connection.java:203)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:169)

- I am using PasswordAuthenticator and CassandraAuth* in Config file.
- Using default Cassandra account(cassandra/cassandra)

Comment: What version of the driver and what version of cassandra?

Comment: The datastax java driver does not work with dse as it relies on C* 2.0 SASL.

Comment: Driver: Earlier I was using 1.0.5 and now 1.0.5-dse
Cassandra: 2.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Th problem is resolved by using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

DSE distributes a patched driver for use with DSE 3.1 authentication.

See https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/1.0 and this...

DSE users should use the following Maven dependency (note the version is set to 1.0.5-dse):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5-dse</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Darlo, 
Thanks for replying. But I am still getting same error even on using maven dependency 1.0.5-dse

Comment: I am also running into this issue and I can't update to the version 2 driver as a third party library depends on 1.0.5-dse.